# Differential equations problem. The details are below, I don’t know how to solve it

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

$$
\text { 4. If }\left(2 x y-y^{2}-y\right) d x=\left(2 x y+x-x^{2}\right) d y \text { and } y(1)=1 \text {, then the value of } 12|y(-1)| \text { is? }
$$

There is an online solution available at: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-2xy-y2-y-dx-2xy-x-x2-dy-and/
But I don’t understand it. Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: In the solution, how did they get to y=-y + y2 – 1?

Comment: Or how do I set up the solution. I don’t rlly understand how to start.

Comment: That solution is kind of wonky.  This is an "exact" equation.  If you google "exact differential equation" you should be able to find a more sensible solution technique.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying idea is that there is a function $f(x,y) = x^2y-y^2x-xy$, which can be differentiated implicitly with respect to $x$ as $$\frac{df(x,y)}{dx} = (2xy-y^2-y) + (x^2-2yx-x)\frac{dy}{dx}.$$ This is equal to zero if the differential equation holds, so $f(x, y) = c$, and $y=1$ when $x=1$, so $c=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, as the previous poster said, $12$. However the structure of the question, the structure of the answer and the overall aesthetic of the exercise is at best shady.

1. The original question asks for the value of $12y(-1)$ without the absolute values.
2. The final answer answers the numerical value of $12y|y(-1)|$.
3. It's not standard notation, at least for me, to translate $y(-1)$ as "what value does the original form give if you plug in $x=-1$" because, as you will see further down, the solution to the differential equation cannot be expressed as a function of $x$ only, so as to write it as a function and therefore $y(-1)$ to be of any value.

At any rate, the mathematics speak for themselves. The original equation is standard form for an exact equation, namely
\begin{align}
(2xy-y^2-y)dx+(x^2-x-2xy)dy=0\\
M(x,y) = 2xy-y^2-y\\
N(x,y) = x^2-x-2xy
\end{align}
and it's exact because
\begin{align}
M_y(x,y)=2x-2y-1=N_x(x,y).
\end{align}

To find the solution function we can integrate either $M$ w.r.t. to $x$ or $N$ w.r.t. $y$ the solution would be the same.

Let $\Phi$ be the solution.

\begin{align}
\Phi(x,y) &= \int (2xy-y^2-y)dx\\
&=x^2y-xy^2-xy+h(y).
\end{align}

We differentiate $\Phi$ w.r.t. to $y$ in order to specify the $h'(y)$.

\begin{align}
\Phi_y&=x^2-2xy-x+h'(y)\\
N &= x^2-2xy-x+0
\end{align}
therefore $h'(y) = 0 \implies h(y) = 0$ (usually we let C of the integration be $0$ and add it in the end in the case of exact equations).

So the solution is
\begin{align}
x^2y-xy^2-xy=C.
\end{align}

Letting $x=1,y=1$ to find $C$ gives $C=-1$.

Here comes the weird part. If we group by $y$, we have
\begin{align}
y = \dfrac{1}{xy+x-x^2}
\end{align}
which cannot be simplified further in a way as to leave only $x$ in it. Therefore the notation $y(-1)$ has no value.

Now if we let $x=-1$, we can do
\begin{align}
y^2+2y+1=0 &\implies (y+1)^2=0\\
&\implies y=-1.
\end{align}
And $12|y(-1)| = 12$ if I take into account only your question.